# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH from AWS API Gateway into Lambda

Tags: ssl, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have set up a lambda and attached an API Gateway deployment to it. The tests in the gateway console all work fine. I created an AWS certificate for *.hazeapp.net. I created a custom domain in the API gateway and attached that certificate. In the Route 53 zone, I created the alias record and used the target that came up under API gateway (the only one available). I named the alias rest.hazeapp.net. My client gets the ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error. Curl indicates that the TLS server handshake failed, which agrees with the SSL error. Curl indicates that the certificate CA checks out.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when my DNS entry pointed directly to the API gateway deployment rather than that backing the custom domain name.

To find the domain name to point to:

```
aws apigateway get-domain-name --domain-name "<YOUR DOMAIN>"
```

The response contains the domain name to use. In my case I had a `Regional` deployment so the result was:

```
{
    "domainName": "<DOMAIN_NAME>",
    "certificateUploadDate": 1553011117,
    "regionalDomainName": "<API_GATEWAY_ID>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    "regionalHostedZoneId": "...",
    "regionalCertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:<ACCOUNT>:certificate/<CERT_ID>",
    "endpointConfiguration": {
        "types": [
            "REGIONAL"
        ]
    }
}
```